# Using function pointer as callback

Tags: c++

In some SDK I have a method which takes function pointer.

```
int AutoRead(nAutoRead aEventFun)
```

where parameter is:

```
typedef int (__stdcall *nAutoRead)(char *data);
```

Now I want to use this function in my code like this:

```
    // First need to get pointer to actual function from DLL
    CV_AutoRead AutoRead; // CV_AutoRead is typedef for using function pointer 

    AutoRead = (CV_AutoRead)GetProcAddress(g_hdll,"AutoRead");

   // Now I want to use the SDK method and set callback function, 
   // but I get error on the next line
   // error is: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int (__cdecl *)(char *)' to 'TOnAutoRead'
   nAutoRead f = &callbackFunc;
   if(0 == AutoRead(f))  // AutoRead - now refers to the SDK function shown initially
   {

   }
```

where `callbackFunc` is:

```
int callbackFunc(char *data)
{

}
```

Apparently I am doing something wrong. But what?

ps. This is typedef for `CV_AutoRead`

```
typedef int (CALLBACK* CV_AutoRead)(nAutoRead aEventFun);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the calling convention specifier `__stdcall` that the callback requires. By default your `callbackFunc` uses `__cdecl`, causing an error.

To fix this problem, declare `callbackFunc` as follows:

```
int __stdcall callbackFunc(char *);
```

You also need to add `__stdcall` to the function definition.

See [*Argument Passing and Naming Conventions*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx) for more information on this subject.

Comment: seems to compile now. Thanks. added _stdcall to both function declaration and definition. ps. Am I using the function pointer correctly ? e.g., `TOnAutoRead f = &callbackFunc;
   if(0 == AutoRead(f))` ??

Comment: __stdcall should go also in the function definition?

Comment: @dmcr_code I think you're right, the doc says that to use `__stdcall` you need to have a prototype, but it looks like `__stdcall` needs to be on the definition as well.

Comment: and finally, just tell me if I use it correctly, e.g., `TOnAutoRead f = &callbackFunc;
   if(0 == AutoRead(f))`?? Is this usage correct? The way I pass func pointer as parameter?

Comment: @dmcr_code That's one way. You can also pass it without making a variable or taking an address, and use `!` to zero-check the return the C style, i.e. `if (!AutoRead(callbackFunc)) ...`

Comment: OK I see. strange in my way you need to use `&` and in the other way (which you showed) you can directly pass `callbackFunc`

Comment: @dmcr_code You can omit `&` in the assignment as well - C treats function names with no parentheses after them as pointers to these functions.

Comment: yep, it was not making sense, that at one place one used `&` and at other, didn't.